# copy image and text to the UIPasteboard

Tags: iphone, uipasteboard

I want to copy image and text (both) to UIPasteBoard.
**Is it possible to copy both the text and image.**

**Here I can copy image only or text only .
How to copy both ?**

My code for copy image is as follows,

```
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:UIPasteboardNameGeneral create:NO];
pasteBoard.persistent = YES;
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
[pasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG];
```

Thanks in advance !!!!!

Answer (score 11):

Here is my code and it is working perfectly on my device.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.persistent = NO;

NSMutableDictionary *text = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
[text setValue:captionLabel.text forKey:(NSString *)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText];

NSMutableDictionary *image = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
[image setValue:gratitudeImageView.image forKey:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG];

pasteboard.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image,text, nil];
```

Comment: Heads up! kUTTypeUTF8PlainText and kUTTypePNG need the MobileCoreServices framework! Or maybe you can find those exact strings and enter there...

Comment: Heads up 2: This does actually not work when trying to send text and image to LINE app... it might be that LINE just doesn't support it. http://media.line.me/howto/en/ (Format 2) for me only the image shows up in LINE.

Answer (score 4):

You should be setting the items property of the pasteboard-

The description of items from the reference is-

> items
>
> The pasteboard items on the pasteboard. @property(nonatomic,copy)
>   NSArray *items Discussion
>
> The value of the property is an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary
>   represents a pasteboard item, with the key being the representation
>   type and the value the data object or property-list object associated
>   with that type. Setting this property replaces all of the current
>   pasteboard items.

So, you can add two dictionaries to an array, with key value pairs being  &  and set this array to the items property.

Comment: Thanks Akshay For your reply

Comment: This is really the Right way to do. Make separate NSDictionary Object for each item. I have done it and it is working for me. See my answer.

Comment: As of iOS8 this no longer works when pasting into the Mail app. If any images are present, they will be pasted instead of text.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the official way simply does not work in iOS.  Instead of creating an individual dictionary for each item and adding those to the array (as stated in the documentation), add all items to a single dictionary, then make an array with that single dictionary and set that to the pasteboard.

Like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary * pasteboardDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[pasteboardDict setObject:someData forKey:someUTIkey];
[pasteboardDict setObject:someOtherData forKey:someOtherUTIkey];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pasteboardDict]];
```

Comment: When I do this with multiple text objects, it appears that any text objects after the first object are truncated on the first carriage return they contain. Have you seen this effect, or were you always using different types? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444590/uipasteboard-truncating-strings-when-pasting-multiple-items-into-mail?rq=1

Comment: Thanks ecume des jours For your reply.

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked a long time ago, but it's still relevant - and especially since Apple docs don't make Swift multi-format UIPasteboard APIs very clear. Having struggled to figure out how to do multiple-format copy & paste, I thought I'd share my solution in case it helped anyone else. In my case, I needed to support an internal format (containing all the particulars), as well as image and text versions for pasting into other apps.

First, you need to get access to the UTI constants - you'll get unresolved symbols without adding this at the top of your file:

`import MobileCoreServices`

Then define your format UTI:

`let my_private_uti = "com.mydomain.myapp.myformat"`

Here's the code for an example multi-format copy (in my case for a music program):

```
externalRepresentation = "[A7]"
internalRepresentation = "A7:0 0 2 0 2 0"
image = UIImage()            
// fill image with chord diagram...

let pasteboard =
    [ [kUTTypeUTF8PlainText as String : externalRepresentation],
      [kUTTypePNG as String: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!],
      [my_private_uti: internalRepresentation]]

    UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasteboard)
```

And now for the the paste. I want to accept my internal format if it's available, and fall back to processing text if it's not. (Don't do anything with a graphical format in my case.)

```
//Handle internal format
if let pastedata = UIPasteboard.general.data(forPasteboardType:my_private_uti, inItemSet:nil)  {
    if pastedata.count > 0 {
        if let ourformat = String(data: pastedata[0] as! Data, encoding: .utf8) {
        // Process ourformat string
        print("Pasted internal representation: \(ourformat)")
        return
        }
    }
}

// Handle plain text format 
if let pastedata = UIPasteboard.general.data(forPasteboardType:kUTTypeUTF8PlainText as String, inItemSet:nil) {
if pastedata.count > 0 {
    if let textformat = String(data: pastedata[0] as! Data, encoding: .utf8) {
        // Process normal text
        print("Pasted external representation: \(textformat)")
        return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it's pointless to set the `persistent` boolean in iOS, from Apple:

> iOS, public (system) pasteboards are persistent, but by default private (application) pasteboards are not. **These private pasteboards do not continue to exist** when the application that creates them quits. However, you can mark application pasteboards as persistent.